# How to transfer large file to http client in golang

Tags: file, http, go, download

I have a handler function which looks like below:

```
func DownloadFileHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    SetResponseHeaders(w, r)
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }
    var err error
    var responseCode int = http.StatusBadRequest
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    file := vars["file"]
    var n int64 = 0
    var reader io.Reader
    Filename := "images/" + file
    f, err := os.Open(Filename)
    if err != nil {
        err = errors.New("File not found")
        goto Error
    }
    reader = bufio.NewReader(f)
    settings.WriteDebugLog(time.Now())
    n, err = io.Copy(w, reader) // this takes a long time if the file is large
    settings.WriteDebugLog(time.Now())
    settings.WriteDebugLog(n / 1024 / 1024)
    responseCode = http.StatusOK
    settings.WriteLog(r, responseCode, nil, GetCurrentFuncName())
    return
Error:
    WriteErrorResponse(w, responseCode, err)
    settings.WriteLog(r, responseCode, err, GetCurrentFuncName())
}
```

But if it is a large file (more than 1GB), the io.Copy takes quite a long time (best case: 1G 13 seconds shown below) and the download process in browser doesn't show up until the process of io.Copy completes. Is there a way to achieve my goal more efficiently? I want the download process to show up in my browser right after I send the download request.

```
2017/05/16 22:32:29 Debug: 2017-05-16 22:32:29.967499719 +0900 JST
2017/05/16 22:32:36 Debug: 2017-05-16 22:32:36.980914163 +0900 JST
2017/05/16 22:32:36 Debug: 1097
```

I tried calling io.Copy with "go io.Copy" then the download process shows up soon but the file size is 0.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use http.ServeFile? https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile

Comment: Thanks! tried this `settings.WriteDebugLog(time.Now())
 http.ServeFile(w, r, Filename)
 settings.WriteDebugLog(time.Now())`
Took 5 seconds to show up for 1GB file

Answer (score 0):

You can do by directing the download to the file server

Please note, that the filename or path you use is relative to your current working directory.

https://play.golang.org/p/RXVtjZnmMQ